# Minishift cannot start in macOS

Tags: macos, networking, openshift, minishift

**General information**

Minishift version: v1.34.3+4b58f89

OS: macOS

Hypervisor: hyperkit

**Steps to reproduce**

```
minishift start --show-libmachine-logs -v 5
```

**Expected**

minishift started successfully.

**Actual**

*Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: IP address never found in dhcp leases file Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for Generated MAC*

**Logs**

```
-- minishift version: v1.34.3+4b58f89
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
Launching plugin server for driver hyperkit
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:50805
() Calling .GetVersion
Using API Version  1
() Calling .SetConfigRaw
() Calling .GetMachineName
(minishift) Calling .GetState
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'hyperkit' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if hyperkit is installed ... 
   Hyperkit is available at /usr/local/bin/hyperkit
   Checking for setuid bit ... OK
-- Checking if hyperkit driver is installed ... 
   Driver is available at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
   Checking for setuid bit ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'hyperkit' hypervisor ...
-- Starting Minishift VM ....Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
Launching plugin server for driver hyperkit
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:50813
() Calling .GetVersion
Using API Version  1
() Calling .SetConfigRaw
() Calling .GetMachineName
(minishift) Calling .GetState
(minishift) Calling .Start
(minishift) Using UUID 91b2bdde-f54b-11eb-b552-1c36bb1ab9e0
(minishift) Generated MAC 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
(minishift) Starting with cmdline: 
...................... FAIL E0804 23:28:48.938399    8469 start.go:499] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: IP address never found in dhcp leases file Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34. Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: IP address never found in dhcp leases file Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
Temporary Error: Could not find an IP address for 56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo vi /var/db/dhcpd_leases
```

add this

```
{
    name=minishfit
    ip_address=192.168.64.3
    hw_address=1,56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
    identifier=1,56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
    lease=0x5e41592a
}
```

then minishift start

if you see time out error like this:

```
Error starting the VM: Error configuring authorization on host: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded.
```

try this:

```
minishift delete --force --clear-cache

minishift start
```

Comment: Where do the ip and hardware addresses come from? Do I have to adapt them to my system?

Comment: Also, "name=minishfit" has a spelling error. (If that matters?)

Comment: This is a DHCP lease, just make sure that the IP address is not used. The name can be named arbitrarily for easy identification

Answer (score 0):

Openshift Cluster are now in version 4.7, I strongly recommend you to used CRC (code ready containers) in replacement of Minishift.
You can download a free version here: https://www.okd.io/crc.html

Comment: CRC requires at least 9GB of memory..
Is there any way I can run CRC in a 8GB RAM machine?

Comment: Command to used is: `crc config set memory XX` but you are right the minimum is 9216 (9GB). As an alternative, You can try Docker Desktop for Mac it's also possible to configure a Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Minishift is not only deprecated, but it will be problematic to install on Mac OSX Monterey. And even though it kind of succeeds installing, various things are broken:

```
$ sudo du -hx -d2 '/'* 2>/dev/null | grep -ve $'M\t' -e $'K\t' -e $'B\t' | sort -k 2 ; echo Finished
# ONLY DELETE NON-ESSENTIAL FILES IN YOUR HOME DIRECTORY
$ softwareupdate --all --install --force
Downloaded macOS 10.14.6 Update
Installing macOS 10.14.6 Update
$ sudo reboot
# Note you may need to run softwareupdate several times depending on how outdated your computer is
# In fact, I would keep updating until you get the latest MacOSX version, which at the time of this writing is macOS Monterery
# Once your system is up-to-date, then install Docker Desktop: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/
# Note if you are using the latest version of OSX and the latest version of Docker Desktop, then it will install and launch smoothly.
% which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
# Now run “brew update && brew upgrade” or install homebrew if not installed:
% /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Caskroom
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.
# Use the hyperkit virtual machine. docker-machine-driver-xhyve is deprecated!
% brew install hyperkit
% brew install docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
% sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
% sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
# THERE IS A HUGE BUG HERE. Basically, the setuid is correctly added to /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit BUT NOT the symlink at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit. Consequently, I had to delete the symlink at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit and then create a hard link to /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit and then add the setuid and change ownership there!
% ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
-r-sr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  11581712 Mar  1  2018 /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
% brew install cask
% brew install --cask minishift
% which minishift
/usr/local/bin/minishift
% sudo vi /var/db/dhcpd_leases
{
    name=minishfit
    ip_address=192.168.64.3
    hw_address=1,56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
    identifier=1,56:bb:6a:61:3c:34
    lease=0x5e41592a
}
% minishift start
```

Instead of using Minishift, you should be using RedHat CodeReady Containers. Instructions for Mac OSX are here (note you must have 35gb of disk space available on your machine):

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_codeready_containers/1.0/html/getting_started_guide/getting-started-with-codeready-containers_gsg

What took 5 hours with minishift, only took 5 minutes with CRC.

Answer (score 0):

for my case, I had my corporation antivirus running (particularly McAfee with a **firewall** activated), which was blocking the creation of dhcpd_leases. After turning that off and shutting the firewall temporarily, it got fixed.