# Cannot start minishift on mac Catalina

Tags: openshift, macos-catalina, minishift

I tried a couple of time to install uninstall and reinstall openshift on 2 macs with os Catalina 10.15.7 but it never starts.

I read [Minishift cannot start in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660617/minishift-cannot-start-in-macos) and installed the var as described. but I still get the error below. Did anybody manage to install it on Catalyna and managed to resolve these errors?

kind regards

Markus

-- Starting Minishift VM ........ FAIL E0423 15:57:02.814314   21785 start.go:499] Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet1 --ip 192.168.99.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 failed:
VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
. Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet1 --ip 192.168.99.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 failed:
VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

Comment: I think you should use CodeReady Container instead of minishift.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_codeready_containers/2.0/html-single/getting_started_guide/index#macos

Answer (score 0):

It seens a virtualbox configuration error about network access deniying. Try this:

1. Access or create file /etc/vbox/networks.conf (or where your vbox configuration file is located)
2. Change the content to: ***0.0.0.0/0 ::/0**